# Single or multiple DbContext File in mvc4 using Entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

i am using entity framework 5 in mvc4 application .i want to ask about multiple DbContexts files in single project. is this a good approach to use multiple dbContext files in single mvc4 project using Entity Framework 5 or should i use only single DbContext File or Multiple please guide me 
 Thank you.

Comment: If you have more than one DB use multiple DbContexts, if you not then use only one DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously stated it is good practice to have a one DbContext file per database. So if you are running for example, a blog and shop these would no doubt be separate databases therefore separate DbContexts. A project I am currently on uses one database and roughly 20 tables, this has one DbContext. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple dbcontexts if:

1. your data is stored in different databases (cause dbcontext working with single database)
2. you have several independent datamodels in single database. (it is good to separate independent data).